# Best type of water to drink?

Tags: water, water-filter-purifier

I have done some reading and it seems to come down to these 2 choices :

1. Spring or Mineral water ( from earth )
2. Reverse Osmosis with added ozone ( any water processed )

As I understand with Reverse Osmosis they remove almost all the contaminants including the minerals in the water but the water does not contain any bacteria, viruses etc.

With mineral water all the minerals are still intact but might contain impurities because it did not undergo a strict filtration process.

What are potential positive or negative health effects of the reverse osmosis water with added ozone when compared with spring/mineral water?

Comment: I have read extensively on this in the past, and there is no clear professional consensus on the answer to this other than ensuring the source and filtration are free of contamination.  Anything beyond that would have to provide pages worth of discussion on the topic without a clear answer at the end, or for individual application would need to be an individual decision with your physician espeically if you have any medical concerns or symptoms.  Therefore I vote to close as opinion based.  If someone has definitive sources that I am unaware of, please provide them; I would be very interested.

Comment: It is a very good question, a valid question, but not one that has a clear answer unfortunately, and therefore not ideal for this site.  I wish there were more research on the topic that could be trusted as truly unbiased. If someone wants to dive into the endless discussions on the topic to provide an unbiased comprehensive digest on it, I'd be thrilled to read it.

Comment: It's impossible to answer generally, which water is better because mineral water is a very broad term. So, I edited the question to focus on potential benefits and harms of each type of water without focusing on which is better.

Answer (score 2):

**MICROBES**

**Bottled spring waters** can contain microbes, which can, rarely, cause infections, for example, in the US, one outbreak in 1999/2000 has been reported ([wcponline.com](http://www.wcponline.com/2005/09/15/microbial-quality-safety-bottled-water/)); some other small outbreaks are mentioned on [CDC.gov](https://www.cdc.gov/healthywater/surveillance/drinking-surveillance-reports.html).

According to one 2010 study in Canada, bottled waters may contain more microbes than tap water ([Telegraph.co.uk](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/health/news/7763038/Bottled-water-contains-more-bacteria-than-tap-water.html)).

**Bottled carbonated mineral waters** have, in general, less bacteria than non-carbonated waters ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16457377)).

**Bottled reverse osmosis waters** should contain very few microbes; they are also additionally treated by ozonation or UV lights ([CDC.gov](https://www.cdc.gov/healthywater/drinking/home-water-treatment/household_water_treatment.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_osmosis)).

**MINERALS**

**Mineral waters** usually contain more calcium and magnesium than tap water, but it is not clear if this has any health benefits ([PubMed, 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3775162/)). We get most minerals from food, not water, anyway.

**Reverse osmosis** waters contain very little of both nutritional minerals and chemical contaminants ([CDC.gov](https://www.cdc.gov/healthywater/drinking/home-water-treatment/household_water_treatment.html)).

---

In summary, it is not possible to say which type of water is better for everyone. Mineral/spring water can have better taste, and reverse osmosis water can be appropriate for individuals with weak immunity, since it contains very little microbes.